# How to set a class wide variable?

Tags: xcode, swift

Just starting with Swift, I'm creating an API service class but I don't understand how I can make this work!?!

```
import UIKit

class Hello {
    var className: String

    init() {
        self.className = "hello"
    }

    class func someFunc() {
        println(self.className = "hello") // <= This doesn't work
    }      
}
```

From what I understand, since I need `someFunc` to be accessible when I call it, I need it to have `class func`. Example, in my view controller, when the user clicks a button, I can do `Hello.someFunc()`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "static variable" or "static property" will be useful search terms.

Comment: in this case you should change `className` to `class var className = "hello"`, or to `static`, and remove it from the `init`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow subclasses to be able to override it:

```
class var className: String { return "Hello" }
```

*(Note that `class` variables cannot be [stored](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255) properties; they must be [computed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259) properties.)*

Otherwise:

```
static var className = "Hello"
```

*(`static` is the same as `final class`)*

You can read more about type properties in the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID264) book.

Your current `println` is failing because you're trying to print an assignment, rather than a string. I suspect you meant something more like:

```
println("ClassName is \"\(className)\"")
```

Although — having said all of that — if you just want to get the name of the class you ought to use:

```
println(self.dynamicType)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to declared class variable as static that way, you can access it inside your class level methods using self. However, if you want to access that from instance method you will have to use class name with it.

```
class Hello {
    static var className: String = ""


    init() {
        Hello.className = "hello"
    }

    class func someFunc() {
        println(self.className = "hello") 
    }
}
```

Also notice that swift expects that the class variable are initialized when they are created.